# How do you create a multi-select people-picker field programatically in SP 2007?

Tags: column, people-picker, multi-select

I would like to create a people-picker user field where more than one user can be chosen.

Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
SPField field = new SPField(contentType.Fields, "User", "Users");
SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(field);
contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);
contentType.Update();
```

However, I imagine this only creates a field to select a single user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to an [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser_members.aspx), or create an SPFieldUser in the first place, and set [AllowMultipleValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.allowmultiplevalues.aspx) to true.

Answer (score 2):

you can use only AddFieldAsXml because Multiselect User Field is marked as non-UserCreatable :)

```
list.fields.AddFieldAsXml(<Field Type="UserMulti" DisplayName="My_User_Field" Required="FALSE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleAndGroups" UserSelectionScope="0" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" ID="{7293d78b-f9b3-4cce-b85f-ac499fc4fcf2}")
```

Comment: Where is it documented that it's non-user creatable? I think I missed it on my quick scan of MSDN...

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Mult="true"` part? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) it is `A scale factor used in multiplication before displaying a number`