# Is there an array-like data type for Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-list

I am looking for an array-like data type to store an array of user emails within Sharepoint list. Is this supported? My alternative is to convert this array into a JSON and then store it as a string.

Comment: Since emails do not contain commas I would store it as CSV string, easier and faster to work with than a JSON Object, with a simple ``.split(",")`` you can use all modern Array methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no array-like data type in SharePoint, it's better to convert this array into JSON and store it as string in multiline text field.

Comment: Found my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/how-do-you-create-a-multi-select-people-picker-field-programatically-in-sp-2007